# Can these two products $(a-b)⋅(a-b)$ and $(b-a)⋅(b-a)$ be considered equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Would it be correct to state that for dot products:
$$ (a-b)⋅(a-b) = (b-a)⋅(b-a)$$

My reasoning is that this equates to:
$$ ||a-b||^2 = ||b-a||^2 $$

which is true.

Comment: The answer reduces to the fact, that $(-1)\cdot (-1)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot product is an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) and that is (S) symmetric, and (L) linear in the first argument:
$$
 \langle a-b, a-b \rangle \underset{(L)}{=} - \langle b-a, a-b \rangle \underset{(S)}{=} - \langle a-b, b-a \rangle \underset{(L)}{=} \langle b-a, b-a \rangle
$$

With respect to your reasoning: It is correct that $\Vert a-b \Vert^2 = \Vert b-a \Vert^2$, but the fact that $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{\Vert x, x \Vert}$ is a norm *uses* the fact that the inner product is symmetric and linear.